# Creating View for two tables and selecting column5 from table1, or from table2 if table1.column1=table2.column1 and table2.column1 exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have 2 tables, both keyed on Item. Rows of Table2 are a subset of rows from Table1, based on matching Item value. So there may be rows in Table1 with  no match on Item in Table2, but there are no rows in Table2 without matching rows in Table1, by Item.

I need several columns from Table1, including Table1.Price. However, if Table1.Item = Table2.Item and Table2.Item exists I want to Select Table2.Price, instead of Table1.Price.

I see that I could use a Left Join to combine rows, but I don't see how I can select one Price value, sometimes from Table1 and sometimes from Table2.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What would the step be to derive a value when 15 records (prices) exist in Table2 for one associated record in Table1?

Comment: It will be easier to understand your requirement if you can provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Typically you would use something like `isnull(tbl2.Price, tbl1.Price) as Price`

Answer (score 1):

Because the Table2 columns will be NULL where there's no match, you can just use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), eg

```
Select t1.Id, coalesce(t2.Price, t1.Price) Price
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
  on t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Comment: Mmm.? Ml. M. Mm

Comment: Mmm m m mmm/m m mm. Mm m.. M mm m.  /m m m../m

Comment: Interesting that you recommend `COALESCE` over `ISNULL` given the performance implications (`COALESCE` does not remove nullability from the return value, and in the case of subqueries can result in executing the subquery twice). There is also the data type issue: `ISNULL` always returns the data type of the first argument, `COALESCE` will use precedence

Comment: I prefer COALESCE because it's ANSI standard and handles any number of arguments.  Full comparison here: [Deciding between COALESCE and ISNULL in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)